# "be considered" and "be referred to as"

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

Do native speakers think there is a contradiction in the following?

> He is considered the best doctor in town, but is never referred to as such.

Comment: It's a little unusual, but I don't see any contradiction here.  I would interpret it to mean "People *think* he is the best doctor in town, but they would never *say* that out loud."

Comment: Is there a contradiction in "He is considered the best doctor in town, but is never regarded as such"?

Comment: I see nothing particularly "unusual"  in *...never **referred to** as such* here, either. But *...never **regarded** as such* doesn't make sense, because the verbs "consider" and "regard" are effectively synonymous here, so you end up with an utterance basically saying *He is X, but he is not X*. What you think and what you say might be different, but what you consider to be true and what you regard as true must be the same.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Agreed. I was asking that because many people in East Asia are taught that "consider A + N" and "refer to A as + N" are interchangeable.

Comment: In that case, many people in East Asia are being taught things that simply aren't true. I think perhaps the confusion arises from the fact that it's perfectly okay to say *We can **treat** X as Y* as a kind of "shorthand" for *X and Y aren't really the same, but to simplify matters in our current context, we will "pretend" they are the same*.

Comment: I can't comment on the entirety of East Asia, but at the very least Chinese distinguishes between 认为 (consider to be) and 称为 (call / refer to as).

Comment: @Chungoli Some Chinese teachers of English do regard "refer to A as B" as a (near-)synonym of "consider A B." https://www.cpsenglish.com/question/28388

Comment: "有些不及物动词加介词，构成短语动词。这些短语动词，有的是可以变成被动语态的。常见的有 ... refer to （认为）等。"

Comment: Oh, interesting. I'd say that that poster is simply mistaken, or made a typo. The other two commenters in the cpsenglish page you linked correctly translate "refer to" as 称为, 称作, 叫, etc.